# TeamCity Project Template

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to have a whole project including all build configurations in a template?

We have a setup where we deploy several applications using TeamCity and the only difference in each deployment is the VCS root.  The build process is the same for each of the applications.

What I have been looking for is a way to have a template for the build configuration so that new applications can easily create the TeamCity project from a template instead of the quickest way we have ATM which is the copy an existing project and change the VCS root.

Any other ideas on this, or thoughts on other ways to approach this would be welcome.

Comment: Did you ever find anything for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, and have found that templates are the way to go. I have a template for the build, and include a parameter for the git repo. Then, in the template, add a VCS root with the address set to the parameter. Works like a charm.